# Calculate $c$ so that $E[c|X_1 - X_2|]$ = 1

Tags: normal-distribution, data-transformation

Given $X_i \sim N(1,1)$ for $i = 1,2$. Determine $c$ so that $E[c|X_1 - X_2|] = 1$

I am a bit confused whether $c$ should be $\sqrt\pi$ or $\frac{\sqrt\pi}{4} $.
If we take $Y = X_1 -X_2$ then $Y \sim N(0,2)$. Then we would have
$$
f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_y}}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2\sigma_y^2}} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt\pi}e^{-\frac{y^2}{4}}, \quad -\infty <y<\infty
$$
This part where I got fuzzy. Note that $|X_1 - X_2|$ will transform $-\infty <x_1-x_2<\infty$ to $0 <|x_1-x_2|<\infty$. But my intuition thought that the pdf will be like Exponential distribution with $\frac{1}{\theta }= \frac{1}{4}$ and it needed to be times by 2. And since the support is non-negative. Hence the expectation for an Exponential Distribution would be 4. Carry out the constant i.e. $\frac{1}{\sqrt\pi}$ (the 2 cancelled out by the transformation). Then $c$ should be $\frac{\sqrt\pi}{4}$ right ?

Comment: Presumably $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent.  $|Y|$ is called a "[half-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution)", not an exponential distribution.  It has expected value $\sqrt{\frac 2 \pi \sigma_Y^2}$ and here $\sigma_Y^2=2$, so neither $\sqrt{\pi}$ nor $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}$ are correct.

Comment: You have the wrong formula for $f_Y(y)$ because you have been the victim of creeping radicalism, which is a disease that causes the radical sign in the denominator to extend over the $\sigma_y$.  Never, EVER, write $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}$; instead, always write $\dfrac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}$ and you will alway bw fine.

Comment: @Henry then $c$ should be $\frac{\sqrt \pi }{2}$ right ?